# Change the View Sequence and Data View Style

Tags: fullcalendar

I want the top buttons Month, Week and Day to be as Day, Week and Month.

Also, can I have scheduler to show multiple sections showing Appointments for different filters. Like I have multiple doctors for which I want the scheduler to show appointments for each of them separately. In a Day View option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from here: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=490
Thanks anyway